# Magento2: How to get Last level category?

Tags: magento2, category

I need last level category of each sub category.
I mean a category which has no child category.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all categories as collection
2. Loop through each of them
3. Use the method `hasChildren()` to find if that category has children or not